# Resource render hook control doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fullcalendar

I struggle to activate a resource label render hook. It works perfectly in the provided example and I've tried to mimic this. However, had no success. No errors, nothing crushed. It's just not active. Here's my JS calendar setup file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

//Initialize calendar
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source', //hide lices=nc=se warning

    plugins: [ 'resourceTimeline', 'bootstrap', 'interaction' ], //connect plugins to page

    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth', //define timeline view

    editable: true, //enable draggable events

    droppable: true, //it allows things to be dropped onto the container

    resourceGroupField: 'group', //grouping

    resourceOrder: 'Projects, Personnel', //order of resources

    resourceAreaWidth: '13%', //resource column width

    resourceLabelText: 'Projects/Personnel', //resource label

    resourcesInitiallyExpanded: true, 

    resourceLabelDidMount: function(arg) {
        arg.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log(arg)
        })
      },

    //resources feeding
    resources: {
        url: 'scheduler/resources',
        method: 'GET'
    },

    //events feeding
    events: {
        url: 'scheduler/events',
        method: 'GET'
    },

    defaultTimedEventDuration: '24:00', //deafult event duration 

    weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO', //first day of week Monday

    //header layout
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today ',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineMonth, resourceTimelineYear,'
    },

    //footer
    footer: true,
    footer: {
    },

    height: 'auto', //calendar window size (including header and footer)

    //text on standard buttons
     buttonText: {
         today: 'Today',
          month: 'Month',
          year: 'Year'
     },

});

calendar.render();
```

});
The calendar is rendered using the Express framework. Perhaps there's a simple line that I've just missed. Very much appreciate any help.

Here's my v.5 scheduler setup file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',

    slotMinWidth: 35,

    nowIndicator: true,

    editable: true, 

    droppable: true,

    resourceGroupField: 'group',

    resourceOrder: 'Projects, Personnel',

    resourceAreaWidth: '13%', 

    resourcesInitiallyExpanded: true, 

    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Projects/Personnel',
    
    resourceLabelDidMount: function(arg) {
      arg.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(arg)
      })
    },

    resources: {
        url: 'scheduler/resources',
        method: 'GET'
    },

    events: {
        url: 'scheduler/events',
        method: 'GET'
    },

    defaultTimedEventDuration: '24:00',

    weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',

    headerToolbar: {
        start: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        end: 'resourceTimelineMonth resourceTimelineYear'
    },

    height: 'auto',

     buttonText: {
         today: 'Today',
          month: 'Month',
          year: 'Year'
     },

});

calendar.render();
```

Two screenshots:

1. [fullcalendar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q9yd.png) In "resource-add-remove" example from fullcalendar site a cursor changes into hand pointer when hovering over a resource label and reacts on click.
2. [codepen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20fU2.png) In the codepen example the cursor remains inactive and does not respond.

Comment: I notice you've specified the `plugins:` option. This option is only valid in fullCalendar v4. However the render hooks such as `resourceLabelDidMount` are only valid in fullCalendar v5. Which version have you actually loaded into your page?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I used version 4.4. Today I updated to v5 but still have no response from the resource label hook.

Comment: Here's my new setup: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth', 
editable: true, 
droppable: true, 
resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Projects/Personnel',
resourceLabelDidMount: function(arg) {arg.el.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log(arg)})},
resources: {url: 'scheduler/resources', method: 'GET'},
events: {url: 'scheduler/events', method: 'GET'},
calendar.render();});` Maybe it's because I use Express?

Comment: Please don't add large quantities of code into the comments - as you can see yourself, it's quite hard to read. Your question has an "edit" button (just underneath the little blue tags) - please use that to update your post and then you can format the code properly. Then I'll take a look at it fully. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've added code to the question. Thank you

Comment: Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/NWxoGoa - your code works fine.

Comment: Hello Andrew. It doesn't work when I open the codepen demo. I added two screenshots to question.  First is showing an example from fullcalendar.io and cursor is changing into hand pointer when hovering over a resource label. In the codepen demo it remains inactive over the entire resources area. Thank you for your support.

Comment: It does work - if you click on a resource it logs to the console, which is what the code you've written is supposed to do. You can watch the console and see this easily. You didn't add anything to change the pointer. You never mentioned this pointer behaviour before, so I just assumed what the requirements were, from the code you've written. You can add CSS easily to change the pointer if you want to.

Comment: P.S. I can't find the demo you're referring to on the fullCalendar site - can you post a link to it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works!!! Both in the codepen demo and in my page. This pointer baffled me. I'll add cursor property in css. Thank you very much for your help. In respect to the fullcalendar demo, it's not on the webpage. I found it in examples that can be downloaded here: [link](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/releases/download/v5.1.0/fullcalendar-scheduler-5.1.0.zip). Again, very appreciate your help. Have a good day.